# Highlight parts of two different curves

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

In the plot generated by

```
    y = 1;
Plot[{Sin[x] x^-2/y, y}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}]
```

how can one highlight the curve as shown below, and possibly fill the region *under* the highlighted portion?

[image]

EDIT: A special request:
[image]

Comment: Why do you define `y=1` when you simplify everything by just using `Plot[{Sin[x]/x^2,1},...]`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork presumably because `y` can take other values?

Comment: @infinitezero:  But that is irrelevant to the problem... see?

Comment: Yes, actually y can take different values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

y = 1;

Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@
   {Sin[x] x^-2/y, y, Min[Sin[x] x^-2/y, y]}], {x, 0, 2},
 PlotRange -> {0, 2},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.7, .8}],
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {Red, Thick}},
 Filling -> 3 -> Bottom]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Per request in comment

```
Plot[Evaluate[Tooltip /@ {
    Max[Sin[x] x^-2/y, y], Min[Sin[x] x^-2/y, y]}],
 {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.84, .35}], 
 Filling -> {1 -> Top, 2 -> Bottom}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank @Bob Hanlon. How can I fill the top right $\{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2) \}$  and bottom left $\{(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$,  sections?

Comment: Almost there! I need only to highlight the top right and bottom left *squares*.

Comment: Add a drawing to show what you want.

Comment: Thanks @Bob Hanlon. Just added a drawing.

Comment: Just use `Epilog` to add two `Rectangle`s

Answer (score 6):

This does not make the line red where you want it to be, but it does highlight the region under the highlighted portion:

```
y = 1;
p = Plot[{Sin[x] x^-2/y, y}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}];
rp = RegionPlot[z < Sin[x] x^-2/y && z < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, BoundaryStyle -> Red];
Show[rp, p]
```

[image]

Edit: I could not plot the two functions together as I kept having color function issues. But I found the intersection of the two functions and defined a ColorFunction so that the functions change color after they intersect:

```
y = 1;
f1 = Sin[x] x^-2/y;
rp = RegionPlot[z < f1 && z < 1, {x, 0, 2}, {z, 0, 2}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> None];
```

```
intersection = Values@First@FindRoot[f1 - y, {x, 1}];

f1Plot = Plot[f1, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, z}, If[x < intersection/2, Opacity[0.5,Blue], Red]]];

yPlot = Plot[y, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, z}, If[x < intersection/2, Red, Opacity[0.5,Orange]]]];
Show[f1Plot, yPlot, rp]
```

[image]

I have no idea why, but I had to use `intersection/2` as x the value at which the colors change...it should just be `intersection` but clearly there's something I don't understand that is going on.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
 y = 1;

 Plot[{Sin[x] x^-2/y, y}, {x, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  PlotLabels -> "Expressions", 
  Filling -> 
   {1 -> {Bottom, LightRed}, 2 -> {Top, White}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

- Solve the equation to find the median point `x0` and split all the curve to two parts by `ConditionalExpression`.

```
Clear[x0];
y = 1;
x0 = x /. 
  Solve[Sin[x] x^-2/y == y, x, 
    Reals][[1]]; Plot[{ConditionalExpression[Sin[x] x^-2/y, 
   0 <= x <= x0], ConditionalExpression[Sin[x] x^-2/y, x0 <= x <= 2], 
  ConditionalExpression[y, 0 <= x <= x0], 
  ConditionalExpression[y, x0 <= x <= 2]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red, Red, None}, 
 Filling -> {{3 -> {Bottom, Darker@Cyan}, {4 -> {Top, Darker@Cyan}}}},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate dynamic anwer:

```
Manipulate[Module[{f, s},
  f[x_, y_] := Sin[x] x^-2/y;
  s = {x, f[x, p]} /. FindRoot[f[x, p] == p, {x, 1}];
  Plot[{f[x, p], p, Min[f[x, p], p]}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Black, Red}, 
   Epilog -> {LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, 0}, s], Rectangle[s, {2, 2}]}]],
 {p, 0.5, 3}]
```

[image]